# Not exporting functions from Python module

Tags: python

If I have a module/file `foo.py` with the following contents:

```
from math import sqrt

def foo():
    pass
```

If I import it in another script, `sqrt` is also defined within the module `foo`.

```
import foo    
dir(foo)
```

The output of which is

```
[..., # other things
 'foo',
 'sqrt']
```

How do I prevent this? i.e., either specify `sqrt` not to be exported, or export only specific functions - in this case, only the user-defined ones. I know for user-defined functions you can define them privately within the module by prefixing with an underscore, but in this case it's not a user-defined function so I can't define it with an underscore prefix.

Comment: Why do you need to prevent this? This is normal python behaviour, you asked a module for all the names defined in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> in this case it's not a user-defined function so I can't define it with an underscore prefix.

Yes, you can:

```
from math import sqrt as _sqrt
```

An alternative is to only import objects in function scopes, where you need them.

(While this may answer your question, I still have no idea why you'd want to do it. Both options are cumbersome and won't make your codebase look any better.)

Answer (score 6):

You can't, but it should never get in the way, it is bound to the `foo` namespace, as `foo.sqrt`. If you import `sqrt` from `math` it will be `math.sqrt`. That is the whole point of namespaces.

If you really want to avoid importing certain names, you might do this:

`from foo import foo, bar, ...`

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
from math import sqrt as sqrt_m
import foo
```

So, you can use

`sqrt_m()` to get the `sqrt` from `math` and
`sqrt()` to get the `sqrt` from `foo`

Answer (score 1):

From imported modules you can `delete` an object if you don't want it imported. If `foo.py` looks like this:

```
from math import sqrt
def foo():
    pass

del sqrt
```

then upon importing, `dir(foo)` shows

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__',
 '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'foo']
```

and then obviously you can still do a `from math import sqrt` wherever you import `foo`.